# way to get new dataset on FDA

Tags: openfda

Is there a way to know when and what new data set is added to a specific endpoint like drugs/events?

we have last modified for a particuklar endpoint, but I want see what all new data is added recently

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do so through API querying. The best way to track this would be to download the data daily and compare to previous results.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead

Comment: I am dealing with drugs/drugsfda, I can redownload the data on daily basis, but is there a way to compare the new data with my old data ? Or I just have to replace the old data with my new one

Comment: That would a programmatic issue to work out with however you're storing the data and beyond our purview.